# Issue with intent filter for opening a file in Android app

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I'm trying to open any file with a `.conf` extension in my android app. Here's what I have in my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="file" />
    <data android:host="*" />
    <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.conf" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="content" />
    <data android:host="*" />
    <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.conf" />
</intent-filter>
```

But, when I tap on a `.conf` file in the Downlaods folder, it says "Can't open file."

Here's what I get when I use [Intent Intercept](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/de.k3b.android.intentintercept/):

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove:

```
<data android:host="*" />
```

from both `<intent-filter>` entries and:

```
<data android:pathPattern=".*\\.conf" />
```

from the `content` one.

File extensions are not used much on Android. Starting with Android Q, *files* are not used much on Android. There is no requirement for a `ContentProvider` to put a file-like extension on a `content` `Uri`, as you can see from the `Uri` in your screenshot.

If you wish to support common `Intent` actions like `ACTION_VIEW`, your best bet is to save the file in a common meta-format (e.g., JSON, XML) with a file extension that matches, then have your `<intent-filter>` filter on the corresponding MIME type. You will need to deal with the possibility that the user chooses a file that was not created by your app, though technically you need to deal with that even with your custom extension.

Comment: I can't remove `<data android:host="*" />` from the `file` one. I get an error. But, I removed that and the `pathPattern` from the `content` one. It works now, but wouldn't that be too generic? I'd like my app to open a very specific file.

Comment: @ataravati: "I get an error" -- what sort of error? "but wouldn't that be too generic?" -- yes, but you do not have much of a choice. Had you used a common file extension that mapped to a common MIME type, you could have limited your `<intent-fitler>` to that MIME type, and cut down the number of candidates. As it stands, apps will consider your app to be a candidate for everything, because you need to be a candidate for everything to be a candidate for your custom stuff. Consider switching to using the Storage Access Framework instead of trying to respond to `ACTION_VIEW`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!